# How to add a sentence before an output in Linux shell?

Tags: linux, shell

Hi there so I am wondering how can I add a short sentence/txt before an output?

```
command: grep -o 'DONE' student_accomodation_records.txt | wc -l
output: 2
```

I am simply calculating the amount of times a word appears in a text file.

how do I say "the amount of times this appears: '2' in the output?

Comment: `echo -n "the amount of times this appears:"; grep -o 'DONE' student_accomodation_records.txt | wc -l` ?

Comment: or `printf 'the amount of times this appears: %d\n' "$(grep ...)"`

Answer (score 1):

Suggesting:

```
echo "the amount of times this appears: $(grep -c 'DONE' student_accomodation_records.txt)"
```

#### Explanation

`-c`  Options prints out count of `grep` matches.

Comment: `-c` will count the number of lines that contain the string DONE, but `-o | wc -l` will count the number of times the string DONE occurs.